# Wordpress database connection issue in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

I tried to setup Wordpress in CentOS (8.4.2105) but ended up with the issue when starting wordpress docker container:
**"Error establishing a database connection"**

This is the step that I did:

**1. **docker-compose.yaml****

```
version: '3.2'
services:
 # Database
 db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   volumes: ['/var/lib/mysql']
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
   networks:
     - wpsite
 wordpress:
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: wordpress:latest
   ports:
     - '8000:80'
   restart: always
   volumes: ['./:/var/www/html/example.com']
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
   networks:
     - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
```

**2. Check DB connection by PHP code**

It returns failed

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('db', 'wordpress', 'wordpress', 'wordpress', '3306'); 
if (!$link) { 
echo 'failed';
return; 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

It's understandable that wordpress can not start because the php code already failed to establish connection to mysql container started as tested above. However I'm still able to login or create a new database in cmd cli. I also follow the setup instruction but still can not figure out what is the cause making database connection issue.

This is the site that I follow:
https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/

What is the root cause and how can I fix it ? Is it because of the docker mysql container ? It seems that the issue is thrown but there are no logs to check.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you take:

```html
environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

So

```html
mysqli_connect(host, username, password, dbname, port, socket)
$link = mysqli_connect('db', 'wordpress', 'password', 'wordpress', '3306');
```

And maybe change this in your **docker-compose.yaml**

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
```

Comment: It doesn't work too. It might because of the network of docker I guess. I'm trying by removing "network" property in docker compose